# Should I give extra information on an existing question when I have the same problem on a different version of Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, editing

I have a problem in my system. I searched for a solution on Ask Ubuntu and I found a question asked about the same problem but for a different version of ubuntu (12.10) and I am running 14.04.

Another issue is the question doesn't provide enough information to answer, and additional information has been requested in comments. There are some answers but they have not yet been accepted. Should I edit the question with the wanted information for my system?

The question is [How do I fix a "Unknown configuration key `foreign-architecture' found in your `dpkg' configuration files." error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230952/how-do-i-fix-a-unknown-configuration-key-foreign-architecture-found-in-your).

Comment: We can't do anything about accepting answers. That said, do any of the answers in that post work for you? If not, what happens when you try them? You could post a new question describing that.

Comment: @muru one of those answer works for me.

Comment: then you don't need to do anything further.

Answer (score 11):

Unless the question is yours to begin with, ***do not add your own debugging information or information about the system you use to the question***.

Editing a question to add that information implies you are the original poster, and know the OP's setup and specific environment, or that your system and the OP's are identical.  This is usually not the case, so if you are editing others' questions to add your own information to it to try and make the question more clear, you're likely to get edits reversed or shot down.

**In cases where you are affected by the same issue but want to specify your information**, instead post a new question, linking back to the other one in your post, and say that its the same issue, but then also add all the missing information for *your* setup that the OP of the original post never added.

---

If one of the posted answers on the original question, though, solves the problem for you, then don't bother writing a new question - just do nothing and acknowledge that the other answer helped you quietly.

---

As for accepted answers or not, we can't do anything about that - only the original poster of the question can accept an answer, and if they've abandoned their post there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: "linking back to the other one in your post" how can I do this? I don't try this feature yet. Can you explain please?

Comment: Copy/paste a link to the original question in your new question to indicate that it is similar.  That's what I mean by "linking back"z

Comment: then why you said "instead post a new question" in your answer.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Because I did.  That is, "Post a brand new question asking the same thing, linking back to the original question indicating that you have a different setup and are providing additional debugging information but are having a similar issue".  This is a misinterpretation of what I meant on your part.